# Error en Trigger en Sql server V 2014

Tags: sql

tengo un Trigger que estoy probando para actualizar el valor de la columna `CurrentFlag` de la Bases de datos `AdventureWorksDW2014`

El Trigger debe permitir  la consulta update si el valor de `CurrentFlag` es `0` o `1`,
Es decir que si en Sql Server yo Hago esto:

```
UPDATE DIMEMPLOYEES SET CURRENTFLAG=0 WHERE EMPLOYEEKEY=1
```

o Esto Otro

```
 UPDATE DIMEMPLOYEES SET CURRENTFLAG=1 WHERE EMPLOYEEKEY=1
```

entonces si se cumplen ambas condiciones debe salir un mensaje en consola que diga algo como esto: `PRINT 'VALOR ACTUALIZADO'`,  Por ende sino se cumplen esas condiciones debe salir igual un mensaje como esto :

```
PRINT ' ERROR VALOR NO SE PUDO ACTUALIZAR, NO ESTA DENTRO DE LOS PARAMETROS PERMITIDOS'
```

Tengo este Trigger que hace algo similar pero no he podido tratar de adecuarlo. este el codigo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NOUPDATE ON DIMEMPLOYEE
FOR UPDATE
AS

IF UPDATE(CURRENTFLAG ) 

    BEGIN
       UPDATE  DimEmployee SET CurrentFlag = H. CURRENTFLAG
       FROM DimEmployee J INNER JOIN inserted H
       ON  J.CurrentFlag = H.CurrentFlag
       WHERE H.CurrentFlag <=1
       RAISERROR('VALOR MODIFICADO.', 10, 1)
    END

    BEGIN
      UPDATE  DimEmployee SET CurrentFlag = H. CURRENTFLAG
       FROM DimEmployee J INNER JOIN inserted H
       ON  J.CurrentFlag = H.CurrentFlag
       WHERE H.CurrentFlag >1
       RAISERROR('NO SE PUEDE MODIFICICAR EL VALOR .', 10, 1)
    END          
Go
```

Comment: alguna ayuda en la verificación de este trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Este trigger es parecido, lo hice y me funciono.

```
CREATE TRIGGER NOUPDATE ON DIMPRODUCT
FOR UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @STOCKLEVEL SMALLINT
SET @STOCKLEVEL =1000

BEGIN
        IF UPDATE(SAFETYSTOCKLEVEL)
          IF EXISTS( SELECT P.SAFETYSTOCKLEVEL FROM DIMPRODUCT P
                       INNER JOIN INSERTED R ON
                          P.SAFETYSTOCKLEVEL = R.SAFETYSTOCKLEVEL
                            WHERE R.SAFETYSTOCKLEVEL <=@STOCKLEVEL)
               BEGIN
                PRINT 'DATOS ACTUALIZADOS'
                 END

             ELSE
                 BEGIN
                   RAISERROR ('LA OPERACION SOLO PERMITE ACTUALIZAR VALORES DE STOCK INFERIORES A 1000',15,1)
                    ROLLBACK
                  END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente lo que buscas es que el trigger controle un valor válido para `CurrentFlag`. Te comento que esto eventualmente se puede configurar como regla en la Tabla, lo cual es más sencillo que un trigger, pero de todas formas, la lógica para validar estos valores podría ser:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NOUPDATE ON DIMEMPLOYEE
FOR UPDATE
AS
   IF UPDATE(CurrentFlag)
   BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE CurrentFlag NOT IN (1,0))
      BEGIN
         RAISERROR ('Los Valores válidos para CurrentFlag son 1 o 0!!',15,1)
      END
   END
END
```

Comentarios:

- El trigger no actualiza la tabla, en este caso simplemente verifica los valores de `CurrentFlag` que estamos actualizando. Esto lo comento, por que el código de tu trigger esta actualizando nuevamente `DimEmployee`
- Recuerda que el trigger de `update` se ejecuta al actualizar un registro o un millón de estos, por lo que la lógica en el trigger debe considerar más de un registro
- Con esto `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE CurrentFlag NOT IN (1,0))` verificamos si alguna de las filas actualizadas, tiene un valor inválido para `currentFlag`, en cuyo caso emitimos un error con `RAISERROR()`
- El `RAISERROR()` invalida la transacción, es decir, finalmente no se actualizan las filas, no usar `RAISERROR()` para emitir un mensaje de éxito.